# Access - Cannot Clear Multi-Value Field Via Form Control

Tags: ms-access, multivalue

I have a relatively simple Access Form that I use to catalog items in a collection I have. It all works beautifully...most of the time. The one thing that I cannot seem to figure out this:

I have one control bound to a Multi-Value field in a table (yes, I know, I know...don't use Multi-Value fields). When editing this field via the Access Form control, I am able to add values and delete values, but if I try to delete ALL values in the field, I receive an error message advising that the record cannot be saved, and Access is not able to move on to the next control.

I've searched the internet for similar issues and found nothing. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone? Please.

Comment: *"Don't use Multi-Value fields"* - you nailed it. (Maybe your table field doen't allow NULL?)

Comment: How do I format it to allow nulls?